# Angular 8 karma is ignoring service request

Tags: angular, unit-testing, http, karma-jasmine, json-server

I've been stuck with this simple unit test.

I have a services with a single http get request, and I have a component with an object list. I've been trying to test the result of this request.

When the test run, I always got an empty array because somehow the services is not running, you can see that only have the component con log result.

I'm using json-server for REST API.

Thanks.

This is my console result:

```
10 02 2020 16:47:39.159:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v4.1.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
10 02 2020 16:47:39.160:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome with concurrency unlimited
 30% building 17/17 modules 0 active10 02 2020 16:47:39.314:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
10 02 2020 16:47:44.928:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
10 02 2020 16:47:45.016:INFO [Chrome 80.0.3987 (Windows 10.0.0)]: Connected on socket **** with id **
LOG: 'component'
Chrome 80.0.3987 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 0 of 1 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
LOG: 'component'
Chrome 80.0.3987 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 0 of 1 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome 80.0.3987 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.102 secs / 0.077 secs)
TOTAL: 1 SUCCESS
```

This is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServicesTestService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllMovies() {
    console.log('services');
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/movies");
  }
}
```

This is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ServicesTestService } from '../../services/services-test.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css']
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service: ServicesTestService){}

  movies: any = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMovies();
  }

  getMovies() {
    this.service.getAllMovies().subscribe(res => {
      console.log('component');
      this.movies = res;
    });
  }

}
```

And my spec file:

```
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture, inject, async, fakeAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ListComponent } from './list.component';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { ServicesTestService } from 'src/app/services/services-test.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

let component: ListComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<ListComponent>;
let servicesTestService: ServicesTestService;

describe("ListComponent", () => {

    beforeEach(async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [
            ListComponent
        ],
        providers: [
            ServicesTestService
        ],
        imports: [HttpClientModule]
      }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(inject([ServicesTestService], s => {
        servicesTestService = s;
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ListComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
    }));

    it("should call getMovies and return list of movies", fakeAsync(() => {

      let response = [];

      spyOn(servicesTestService, 'getAllMovies').and.returnValue(of(response))

      component.getMovies();

      fixture.detectChanges();

        expect(component.movies).toEqual(response);
    }));
  });
```

Comment: your test is running as expected, you've mocked getAllMovies and returned an empty array. after getMovies call [] gets assigned to movies.

Comment: But, the rest api return 7 rows, It should run as I expected with that 7 rows.

Comment: @elchente23 : Take a look at https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/testing-a-component-with-stub-services-and-spies-in-jasmine-1428d4242a49.

Comment: Thanks for the link @ShashankVivek. Obviously I had no idea how the unit test works. Its works now.

Answer (score 0):

Here it's not working cause

```
spyOn(servicesTestService, 'getAllMovies').and.returnValue(of(response))
```

This mocks your api call and [] is returned.
Anyways it's not advised to call actual api in unit tests. You can use httpclienttestingmodule to unit test http calls.

To unit test getMovies you can change response from [] to whatever response you're expecting to get assigned in component.movies.

FYI-[unit testing http calls](https://alligator.io/angular/testing-httpclient/)